Quantlib Hull-White long term rate simulation
I have an idea of how to simulate short rate in Hull-White 1F model using QuantLib (Hull White Term Structure Simulations with QuantLib Python). I am not sure if there is any way to simulate a long-term rate (for example, 10 Yr swap rate) from the short rate paths. There exists a formula for converting short to long term in HW model which looks like below
$R(t, T)=-\frac{\ln A(t, T)-B(t, T) r(t)}{(T-t)}$
where $A(t,T)$ and $B(t,T)$ are given by
$\begin{aligned} P(t, T)= & e^{-R(t, T)(T-t)}=A(t, T) e^{-B(t, T) r(t)} ; \\ B(t, T)= & \frac{1-e^{-a(T-t)}}{a} ; \\ \ln A(t, T)=\ln & \frac{P(0, T)}{P(0, t)}-B(t, T) \frac{\partial \ln P(0, t)}{\partial t} \\ & \quad-\frac{\sigma^2}{4 a^3}\left(e^{-a T}-e^{-a t}\right)^2\left(e^{2 a t}-1\right) .\end{aligned}$
Is there some way to get $R(t,T)$ directly in Quantlib ? I am looking to simulate a 10 Yr swap rate path as shown in the plot below.

Thank you,
Yosh
